# Getting error while putting an array onto state - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, api

I'm receieving an array from a Express back-end running with a MongoDB and am currently retrieving an array with the .toArray() function, everything's fine on the back-end.

So the issue is when I'm receieving the array on the front-end, I'm trying to pass it onto state with setState function and it gives me this error

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, uploaderId, uploaderName, title, subtitle, description, language, category, subcategory, currency, price, contents, likes, dislikes, coverImage, coverVideo}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

[Here's an image of the object structure (the courses property is the one that has the retrieved array from the back-end)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isxp8.png)

And the actual code is looking like this

```
axios({
                url: "/course/data",
                method: "GET",
                params: {id: userInfo._id},
            }).then(response => {
                userInfo.courses = response.data;
                console.log(userInfo);
                this.setState(userInfo);
            }).catch(err => err ? alert(err) : null);
```

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong! Your react component should return valid HTML markup, or null.  
What is aforementioned component returning  ?

Comment: Oh thank you, I didn't notice it, but I had {this.state.courses} somewhere in the code which I forgot to remove. I removed it and it's fine now! Thank you really much
@Frosty619

Comment: Happy to help! You may upvote the comment to show your appreciation :D

Comment: I didn't even know you could upvote comments till now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I had a {this.state.courses} tucked up somewhere in my Code, where it should've been {this.state.courses.length}, therefore removing it fixed the issue just like @Frosty619 said.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
axios({
    url: "/course/data",
    method: "GET",
    params: {id: userInfo._id},
}).then(response => {
     userInfo["courses"] = response.data.courses;
     this.setState({userInfo:userInfo});


}).catch(err => err ? alert(err) : null);
```